# Using Google Maps to search zipcodes in my database

Tags: php, mysql, database, api, google-maps

I have a database with zipcodes. I would like to use the Google Maps API to search zipcodes in my database that are within a 5 mile radius of a zipcode I enter.

For example, I put in 33180. I want to retrieve from my database all the zipcodes/areas close to 33180, using Google Maps API.

```
QUERY * FROM zipcodes WHERE zipcode=zipcodes within 5 miles of 33180 (produced by Google Maps API)
```

Is this possible with Google Maps API? Where can I start if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do this with the google maps api alone, you need some server side language to query your database.

Tutorial written by google:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use a zipcode database (like [this free zipcode database](http://www.lustforge.com/2011/07/20/really-free-zipcode-database-download/)) which has geocoded all zips in the US. Then, just write a query that does the simple lat/lng distance calculation and returns the top N results. This will run much much faster than using Google's API, and you won't have to worry about daily API limits.